# How to hide button when second is pressed and how to make it appear when i click on empty area of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, hide, show

I have 2 fields **email** & **password**. Also I have 2 buttons **Sing in** & **Sing up**. I want "Sing up" button to be hidden when "Sing in" is clicked and vice versa ("Sing in" button to be hidden when "Sing up" is clicked). I tried **onmousedown** and **focus**, but then it didn't let me to fill these fields. Here's a fiddle: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrogj3e/2/)

```
<input type="text" id="email" style="display:none;">
<input type="password" id="pass" style="display:none;">
<button id="hide">Sign in</button>
<button id="show">Sign up</button>

<script>
$("#hide").one("click", showFields);
function showFields()
{
$("#email").show();
$("#pass").show();
$("#singup").hide();
$("#singin").on("click", function(){
window.open("#", "_self");
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Naming buttons "hide" and "show" can be misleading.

Comment: If you hide "sign in" when clicking "sign up", then how do you do the opposite? You can't click "sign in" anymore because it's hidden.

Comment: I want the fields to be hidden as default. 
**1) when I click sing in I want singup button to be hidden and the fields to be shown.**
**2) when I click sing up I want singin to be hidden and the fields to be shown**
**3) if i click an empty area I want everything to return to default.**

Comment: Your comment is very different than your original post. Originally, you asked for the buttons to hide each other, and nothing about some blank area that would restore everything. Be specific.

Comment: `Ok but how about the fields?`  --> According to what you're asking for, the fields are always visible, I don't see what's hard to do. You want : 1) the fields to be shown and 2) the fields to be shown (from your own comment above).

Comment: I may need to learn english better (I'm not a native-speaker) :D.. sad story. I couldn't explain what do I need. Anyway, thnx for attention. I'll find another way.. :/

Comment: I don't think it's language level related. I'm not a native English speaker either. You just said the same thing in each case and omit details, which makes solving the problem a little bit hard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#hide").on("click",showFields);

function showFields()
{
    $("#email").show();
    $("#pass").show();
    $("#show").hide();
    $("#hide").on("click", function(){
        window.open("#", "_self");
    });
}

$('button,input').focusout(function () {
    $('#email').hide();
    $('#pass').hide();
    $("#show").show();
    $("#hide").show();
});
```

not sure if it is what you wanted, but I think you should use focusout. But have in mind that you have to list all your elements (in this case, just buttons and inputs) and if you click outside any of those, it will trigger the function.

Comment: [Result](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrogj3e/16/)

Thnx to @thiago-santos . you helped me

Comment: You're welcome. Although my response was not exactly what you were looking for, I'm glad to help